# Tomcat - Is there a way to spew the current/active requests that have not yet responded?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, web-applications

I'm having a hard time debugging a problem with long running response times.  My web application sometimes takes a long time to respond and I'm having a hard time nailing down the specific requests that are the culprits.  The trouble I'm having is that tomcat only logs to the access log once it responds to the request.  I'm wondering if there is a way to either log all incoming requests the moment they come in (and not wait for a response) or tell tomcat to spew out all the requests that it is currently handling (something analogous to jstack, but instead of showing me threads show me the current/active request urls)?

Answer (score 2):

Once served, the slow requests can be identified by activating the [Extended Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve) with the *time-taken* token. It's not your real question, as you want to see in real time, but it's not clear if you already identified *long time to respond* requests.

[VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) will *show you the running threads* but it's not enough to understand what's going on. Probably you again need to activate the Extended Log Valve, this time with the *x-threadname* token to compare with what you have seen in VisualVM. But for the debugging itself, the solution above (time-taken token) is usually enough.

But it not might be enough to identify the bottleneck particularly if the application does in fact have no problem at all (and it seems to be a **random** problem). Does the application use a database ? If so, activate the *slow query log* for example with [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html). Does it use any other tier (authentication, NFS/CIFS,..) ? If so, you need to monitor their availability, in case they are blocking anything when not available.